# Why NSWindow animator setFrame:display:animate: didn't work sometimes?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-animation

I'm new to Cocoa.
And I'm working on extending a project's function.

The original function of that project is open a file and display the file icon in a nsbox(which is in nswindow?)

And when I click the menu to open, it works fine.
But when I open the file programmatically(using the same openfile function which the menu called), it don't show the file icon.

```
[[self.window animator] setFrame:frame display:YES animate:YES];
```

the frame is correct, but it doesn't changed.

Is there anything I missed?

You can comment so I can provide more detail.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I know what's going on now. I'm so stupid.

When I click the button, it's on main thread.

But when I call it on web request, it's not on main thread.

So, please make sure you do anything related to animation on main thread!

Answer (score 1):

`setFrame:display:animate` is a selector on the window object not the animator.

```
[self.window setFrame:frame display:YES animate:YES];
```

Comment: But the origin project use `animator` works perfect. Without `animator` it works but also lose the animation.

Comment: @mxcl: [`animator` gives a proxy to a `NSWindow` object](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsanimatablepropertycontainer/1530511-animator?language=occ). Thus, `setFrame:display:animate:` is also a selector from the animator.