# Set NSWindow Size programmatically doesn't work

Tags: macos, nswindowcontroller

I'm new to macOS and have a very simple project with just one label in the ViewController. In the WindowController I'm trying to set the size of the window with that code:

```
    import Cocoa

class WindowController: NSWindowController {

  override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()
    if let window = window, let screen = NSScreen.main {
      let screenRect = screen.visibleFrame
      print("screenRect \(screenRect)")

    window.setFrame(NSRect(x: screenRect.origin.x, y: screenRect.origin.y, width: screenRect.width/2.0, height: screenRect.height/2.0), display: true, animate: true)
      print("windowFrame \(window.frame)")
      }
  }
}
```

The log shows:

```
screenRect (0.0, 30.0, 1680.0, 997.0)
windowFrame (0.0, 30.0, 840.0, 499.0)
```

However, the window isn't affected, i.e. whatever I enter as width/height, it stay the same. If I change the size with the mouse, next time I open it, exactly the old size.

[image]

Any idea what I may missed in storyboard or anywhere else? Seems to me that I forgot something as it is so basic.....
(The label is constraint to the top, left, right)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it, thanks to PUTTIN [Why NSWindow animator setFrame:display:animate: didn't work sometimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166338/why-nswindow-animator-setframedisplayanimate-didnt-work-sometimes)

The magic thing is, to have it on the mainThread

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
window.setFrame(NSRect(x: screenRect.origin.x, y: screenRect.origin.y, width: screenRect.width/1.0, height: screenRect.height/1.0), display: true, animate: true)
  print("windowFrame \(window.frame)")
    }
}
```

Now it works!

Comment: Is the main thread the magic thing or the async dispatch? Isn't `windowDidLoad` always called on the main thread?

Comment: no, its not. that's the way it works, what do you expect?

Comment: I expected `windowDidLoad` on the main thread. I didn't expect another thread in a very simple project. I expected the order to be the fix.

Answer (score 0):

... did load...

```
   // decide if needed..
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + 0.5
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: {  [weak self] in

        self?.setSize()

    })
}   //setupUI


private final func setSize(){
    if let w = self.view.window{
        var frame = w.frame
        frame.size = NSSize(width: 800, height: 600)
        w.setFrame(frame, display: true, animate: true)

    }
}
```

note: on didLoad without a small delay it does not work. (nil refs...)

Comment: thx, but it seems to work, just with the mainThread..(strange)

Comment: apart from executing on main thread for UI updates(as Apple requires..) You cannot call it on didLoad, as "w = self.view.window". is NIL on didLoad.